# pm2 v1.0.2 and its INTERACTOR_LOG_FILE_PATH

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am running an old pm2 v1.0.2 and have been seeing the following in the interactor log:

> [REV] Connection closed
> [REV] Retrying to connect freenode-5.keymetrics.io:43554
> [REV] Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 51.15.24.186:43554
> at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
> at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1075:14)

How do I fix this hopefully without upgrading the pm2?